# How to receive event callbacks using RCTEventEmitter in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

After updating react-native code from 0.28 to 0.30, subclassing `RCTEventEmitter` is the recommended way for sending events back to Javascript and the old way is deprecated.

```
- (void)startObserving{}

- (void)stopObserving{}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents{

    return @[@"someInterestingEvent"];
}

-(void)interestingEventHappen{
    [self sendEventWithName:@"someInterestingEvent" body:nil];
}
```

The problem is how do I receive the callback rather than just registering the event. I notice `RCTEventEmitter` has method `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addListener:(NSString *)eventName)` exposed, but it only receives one argument(the event name). I tried the document:

`NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('someInterestingEvent', ()=>{});`

with no results and the yellow box complaines sending `someInterestingEvent` with no listeners registered.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [question](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8714) has already been discussed on github.

In short you have to use the `NativeModules` module to get this native module and wrap it in `NativeEventEmitter` class so that you can receive events.

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

const myModuleEvt = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyModule)
myModuleEvt.addListener('sayHello', (data) => console.log(data))
```